# How to calculate radioactivity concentration of components in reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

I understand the reactor parts will become radioactivity because there are neutron flux in reactor. How should we calculate the reactivity of reactor parts? For example lets say there is a reactor core with thermal neutron flux of 1n/cm^2. If there is a steel board been exposed directly to the neutron flux for this 10 years, how do we calculate its radioactivity concentration?

Can anyone give me some key words I could look into?

Comment: Are you looking for a student-assignment level explanation of neutron activation? Or are you interested in a tour of the tools available at the [Radiation Safety Information Computational Center](https://rsicc.ornl.gov/), where the industry standards are? Or somewhere in between?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! I am an engineering student. Please explain it in student-assignment level!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are laws of activation (and deactivation) of materials. In a simple way, the activity is proportional to the number of target nuclei, to the flux of neutrons, to the cross section of activation.
In practice, these basic notions become very complex:
You must know the exact composition of the materials, take into account the radioactive filiations (Batman's equations), have the irradiation diagram (running periods, power of the running stages, reactor shutdown time), neutrons reactor are not mono-energetic, the cross sections vary with the energy, which will lead to multigroup calculations at each point of the material.
But all this is satisfactorily resolved today.
There are powerful neutron calculation codes in 2d, 3d,
taking into account all these variables, some codes even using probabilistic Monte-Carlo methods.
The application of these codes is the work of a specialist in neutronics using these codes full time.